# Поля с атрибутами NULL. Как быть? Он нужен!

Tags: django, django-orm, django-model, django-filter

Всем привет! 
Изучаю `django`, параллельно `ORM` и структуры полей.
Очень смущает свойство поля "`null`", по умолчанию `null=False`.
 Различие между `blank` и `null` я понял, но мне именно необходимо чтобы в таблице вместо пустых строк были значения `null`, тк это удобно и есть определенный стандарт чтобы избежать допущения лишних символов
К примеру,`News.objects.filter(content__isnull=True)`, те поставил `isnull=True` в условии и нашел значения, вместо `content=''`, и если `content` будет содержать дополнительный пробел, то уже `content=''` рабоать не будет.
Загвостка заключается в том, что в документации имеется след рекомендация

> Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and TextField. If a string-based field has null=True, that means it has two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty string. In most cases, it’s redundant to have two possible values for “no data;”

Избегать использование `null` в полях `CharField` и `TextField`. 
Как быть?  Может в моделях указать: 
`content=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default=None`

Comment: создавал поля типа: 
field1(null=True, blank=True) # есть вроде null
field2(null=False, blank=True) # есть пустая строка ' '.
Просто интересно зачем это в рекомендации описано?!

Comment: Рекомендация такая, потому что это текстовые поля. Логично по умолчанию использовать пустую строку. None больше подходит для integer или json полей (имхо)